# asp.net file upload check always returning invalid MIME type

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

i have a user profile page that displays the user's avatar, and allows them to upload a new one.

when the user clicks upload, i want to check the MIME type of the posted file before deciding whether to upload it.

this is all contained in a user control within the parent profile page.

my user control:

```
    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgAvatar" runat="server" OnClick="imgAvatar_Click" /> 
    <asp:FileUpload ID="fluFileUpload" runat="server" AllowMultiple="false" /> 
    <asp:Button ID="btnFileUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="btnFileUpload_Click" /> 
    <asp:Button ID="btnCancelUpload" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClick="btnCancelUpload_Click" />
```

my upload button code behind:

```
    protected void btnFileUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(fluFileUpload.HasFile)
    {
        HttpPostedFile avatar = fluFileUpload.PostedFile;
        bool validmime = validUpload(avatar);
        if (validmime)
        {
            //handling valid upload
        }
        else
        {
            //handling invalid upload
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //handling no file
    }
}
```

my handler for checking the MIME Type:

```
    [DllImport(@"urlmon.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private extern static System.UInt32 FindMimeFromData(System.UInt32 pBC,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] System.String pwzUrl,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] pBuffer,
        System.UInt32 cbSize, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] System.String pwzMimeProposed,
        System.UInt32 dwMimeFlags,
        out System.UInt32 ppwzMimeOut,
        System.UInt32 dwReserverd);
    public static bool validUpload (HttpPostedFile postedFile)
    {
        HttpPostedFile file = postedFile;
        byte[] document = new byte[file.ContentLength];
        file.InputStream.Read(document, 0, file.ContentLength);
        System.UInt32 mimetype;
        FindMimeFromData(0, null, document, 256, null, 0, out mimetype, 0);
        System.IntPtr mimeTypePtr = new IntPtr(mimetype);
        string mime = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(mimeTypePtr);
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(mimeTypePtr);

        if (mime == "image/png" || mime == "image/jpeg" || mime == "image/pjpeg")
        {
            //file is valid  
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            //file is invalid  
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

unfortunately, this is returning an invalid MIME Type even when I know it to be valid (i.e i am uploading a valid .png image but getting an invalid return)

any suggestions on where i'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to documentation of FindMimeFromData ([MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775147(v=vs.85).aspx):

> When uploading files from the client to the Web server, Windows
>   Internet Explorer uses FindMimeFromData to determine a MIME type.
>   Where possible, FindMimeFromData returns hard-coded values from the
>   list of Known MIME Types rather than relying on the MIME type value
>   associated with the file name extension in the system registry. In
>   some cases, the detected MIME type can differ from the generally
>   accepted value for backward compatibility, as shown in the following
>   table:

```
Standard MIME    TypeFindMimeFromData Returns
image/jpeg       image/pjpeg
image/png        image/x-png
```

I would suggest checking for mime == "image/x-png" as well.

Comment: fantastic, that's the answer - i got the types from a list that had ".x-png" as a file extension but still had the mime type as "image/png" . have added "image/x-png" as a mime type to check and it works. thanks very much for the help